# Storing data from database in a CLOB object using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE BULK COLLECT INTO

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I am trying to write a procedure that will populate a CLOB object with certain data from database.

I have a SQL select query stored in a table. I am fetching that query and executing it in the procedure to get a column of data (supplier id).
The reason why I have the query stored in DB is because it is subject to change frequently but it will provide the same column as its result.
Now I am trying to put this data in a CLOB object and this is where I am stuck.
I am unable to get the supplier ids from the v_report_type in the CLOB object.

Can someone please guide me to write the proper code.

Below is the snippet of what I wrote in the procedure.

```
DECLARE

TYPE report_type IS TABLE OF supplier.supplier_id%TYPE
v_report_type report_type;

v_query1 varchar(4000);

v_report_clob CLOB;


BEGIN

v_report_clob:= null;

select query1 into v_query1 from report_query where report_id = 20;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query1 BULK COLLECT INTO v_report_type;


v_report_clob := v_report_clob||v_report_type;


//Unrelated code here

END;
```

Regards
Nirmalya

Comment: What happens now? What error do you get? What do you want the CLOB to look like - do you want the column values to just be concatenated together, or to be delimited somehow? And what is the data type of the ID column?

Comment: I am getting the below error in the line 
`v_report_clob := v_report_clob||v_report_type;`

`ORA-06550: line 17, column 15:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 17, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored`

Comment: @Alex Poole The main purpose is to insert the CLOB in another table. I want to see the supplier ids one below the other. The data type is varchar2(10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that I see in your code is that you are trying to concatenate CLOB with the collection data type. You can try to replace the line with concatenation by:

```
v_report_clob := v_report_clob || v_report_type(1); --always take only first value
```

or

```
FOR i IN 1..v_report_type.COUNT LOOP
  v_report_clob := v_report_clob || v_report_type(i); --concatenate all values into single CLOB, here you can add also e.g. extra spaces between values
END LOOP;
```

Comment: This one worked with a minor correction in the for statement. Thanks a lot.

`FOR i IN 1..v_report_type.COUNT LOOP
  v_report_clob := v_report_clob || v_report_type(i);
END LOOP;`